# Load Fragments for Tabs of TabLayoout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am having a tabLayout in my activity file and having 3 tabs. I want to show the first tab selected and need to load a fragment for this tab at the same activity.

But I need to load other fragments in a new activity when I will click on any tab.

Example: I am having 3 tabs: first tab will be selected default and the fragment related to it will be loaded in the same activity, when I will click on that tab again that time that fragment will be loaded in a new activity, how can I achieve this.

I have the below code:

```
TabLayout mSlidingTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingTabs);
TabLayout.Tab newTab = mSlidingTabs.newTab();
newTab.setText(tabLabel);
newTab.setTag(tabName);`enter code here`
if(i == 0)
  mSlidingTabs.addTab(newTab, i, true);
else
  mSlidingTabs.addTab(newTab, i);
```

I have used mSlidingTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

Please help me if you have any idea to achieve this here, your help is much appreciated..

Comment: you can use viewpager http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void updateTab(String tabId, int placeholder) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) {
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(placeholder, new MyListFragment(tabId), tabId)
                        .commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have used Viewpager with TabLayout and now using mSlidingTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

But I want to load only first tab's fragment here, for both the other tabs I want to load fragments in a new activity.

When the control will come back to this activity need to load the first tab content only.